# Prevent apps on iPhone from triggering icons on Mac dock

Tags: macos, iphone, dock

There's some weird linkage between my iPhone and Mac.  When I go into certain apps, it brings up an icon on my Mac.  I do not want this ever.  How can I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → General and disable ‘Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices’.

This feature is called Handoff, part of Continuity. You can read more about it in the Apple KB:

- [Use Continuity to connect your Mac, iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204681)